# Can't move objects in the scene

Tags: objects

[image]

Got so far with this scene then all of a sudden I'm stuck. I can select objects in both object and edit mode but they will not move. If I select an object in edit object mode and scale it the entire scene scales, not just the selected object Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You've enabled the Proportional Editing option, which may explain, if you enable it in Object mode it won't enable it in Edit mode though

Comment: Apart from _Proportional Editing_ you have also enabled _Snapping_. Do the objects not move at all or are they not moving smoothly... like snapping to increments?